# How to TRIM email in MSQL to only leave domain without duplicates (Only 1 domain)

Tags: sql-server, database, trim

I have Email column in my MSQL server and I need to trim the emails to only leave domains. So everything on the left side of @ including "@" needs to go away. At the same time I only need 1 domain so like no duplicates..

**Example:**

```
Column name = Domains

TEST@EXAMPLE.COM
TEST2@EXAMPLE.NET
TEST3@EXAMPLE.COM
         .
         .
         .
```

------- from -> to -------

```
Column name = Domains

EXAMPLE.COM
EXAMPLE.NET
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: trimmed email address so only the domain of that email stays there. And I cant have duplicate domains in the new table column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (foo varchar(100));
INSERT @foo
VALUES
('TEST@TESTCOMPANY.COM'),
('TEST2@TESTCOMPANY2.COM'),
('TEST3@TESTCOMPANY.COM')

--fun version
SELECT DISTINCT
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(foo, '@', '.'), 2) + '.' + PARSENAME(foo, 1)
FROM
    @foo

--deals with more than 3 dots
--8000 allows us to *not* know the actual string length. It "just works"
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(foo, CHARINDEX('@', foo)+1, 8000)
FROM
    @foo
```

Comment: Is there a chance for me to only work on already existing column? I have over 7000+ emails stored in a column Domain and all I would like to do is update that column to remove multiple hits of same domain and at the same time trim the email to only leave domain.

Comment: I answered the question asked.. The answer to your un-asked question is "yes, you can"

Comment: @Vissow you have other columns in that table? What do you want to happen to the data from additional columns in other rows when you pare down to the one row for each domain?

Comment: No there is only 1 column next to it and it is empty at the moment. The rows should delete with duplicates